# I've toggled my blog posts using jQuery but I would like to have all the other posts close when one is clicked

Tags: jquery

I've toggled my blog posts using jQuery. At the moment I'm able to have all posts open at the same time, but I would prefer to have all posts close when one is clicked. What do I need to add to my jQuery code to do this?

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.toggle-section').hide();
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('.entry-title').click(function() {
$(this).closest('.post').find('.toggle-section').slideToggle();     
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $('.entry-title').click(function() {
        var clicked = this;  // take a reference of clicked element
                             // to use it within hide() callback scope

        // hide all visible sections
        $('.toggle-section:visible').hide(function() {
            // show the clicked
            $(clicked).closest('.post').find('.toggle-section').slideDown();
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

You should aggregate your all code split into two parts:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
      $('.toggle-section').hide();  // initial hide

      $('.entry-title').click(function() {
        var clicked = this;  // take a reference of clicked element
                             // to use it within hide() callback scope

        // hide all visible sections
        $('.toggle-section:visible').hide(function() {
            // show the clicked
            $(clicked).closest('.post').find('.toggle-section').slideDown();
        });
        return false;
     });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I've tried this but now when I click the .entry-title the .toggle-section doesn't appear.

Comment: I tried making a fiddle but I've got lots of PHP in the HTML so it's messing up. Are there any other ways to solve this?

Comment: @user1636968 instead of `slideToggle()` use `slideDown()`